# How can data in a public computer be protected from being copied?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I recently bought several computers for my students which are running Windows 7.  I saved some course materials for my students to look at while in the classroom.  I want these files to be protected from being copied to another storage device.

Computers are not connected to internet so I don't worry about the files being e-mailed.
However, there are usb ports, and I am worried that students might use their flash drive to copy those files.

Of course, I can break the usb ports and there will be no issue. 
However, resale price will drop incredibly when I need to exchange those computers.

I do not care if students make modifications or delete files.
All I care is to keep the files from being copied.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can do lots of things like lock down the usb ports, but in the end, physical access == root access. there is nothing you can do to protect data on a device that is physically in someone elses hands, except encrypt it, and that won't work for you since they do need to be able to access it legitimately. There are some DRM schemes that would do what you want, but nothing that an end user can use without substantial investment.

Comment: Remove the ability to use USB devices from the User group.

Comment: The students are not really into copying the files. I just want to eliminate any easy way to copy those files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do three things with the computers:

1) Disable the USB ports in the BIOS and lock the BIOS with an administrative password. This won't stop a BIOS reset, but that then becomes a policy issue (i.e, obviously students shouldn't be allowed to open the cases).

2) Unplug the USB headers from the motherboard. This completely disables them. As with #1, if the case can be opened the headers can be plugged back in, but nothing will stop a determined tech ;)

3) Revoke USB access from within Windows. There are ways even around this (live CD) but this would likely be the easiest.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!! I didn't know that the USB ports can be disabled. The students definitely will not open the computer.

Comment: It's somewhat BIOS-dependent, but most modern ones can.

Comment: urgh!!!!!!!!!!! the mouse doesn't work as well. It is not an option...sigh... USB ports are onboard. should I look up the motherboard setting and do something about the jumper? does it going to work?

Comment: Unfortunately you may be out of luck using the BIOS, but there's a [number of tricks](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-enable-usb-windowunlock-pen-drive-at-office-or-school-computer) you can try.